# Is Wordpress fully compatible with IIS 8?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, iis-8

I am planning to user wordpress ( CMS tool) with IIS 8 verion instead of apache server as I need to develop training site. Just need to check if wordpress is compatible with IIS.

I don't wont to get into situation where I start development work and after 2-3 month I realized there are some compatiblity issue.

I also need to commit client about this . Please let me know if I can be sure about this

Comment: yes, it is fully compatible with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is a PHP application that requires MySQL. Most if not all IIS servers are fine to run WordPress. If in doubt, see https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

You need at a minimum:

> PHP 5.6 or greater
>
> MySQL 5.6 or greater
>
> The mod_rewrite Apache module

One caveat is mod_rewrite. See [Using Permalinks without mod rewrite « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite) on how to set up Microsoft's URL Rewrite Module, if needed. Some IIS boxes do not run mod_rewrite by default.